# Converting a string a number (exactly as it is represented in it)?

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
{:department=>{"Pet Supplies"=>{"Birds"=>"16,414", "Cats"=>"243,384",
"Dogs"=>"512,186", "Fish & Aquatic Pets"=>"47,018",
"Horses"=>"14,749", "Insects"=>"359", "Reptiles &
Amphibians"=>"5,794", "Small Animals"=>"19,797"}}}
```

Now if I use `to_i` I get say 16. If I do `to_f` I get something like 16.0 (and as you can see Ruby is considering the `,` as a `.` for some reason).

I want the number to be exactly as in the string but as a number instead: `"Birds"=>16,414`

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
"16,414".gsub(",","_").to_i
# => 16414
```

or(as ***@Chris Heald*** suggested)

```
"19,797".delete(",").to_i
# => 19797
```

Comment: You want `gsub` rather than `gsub!` since the latter will return nil if no replacements are made. Or you could just use `delete(",")`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald And you probably don't want to mutate the string in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Just a notice:

> If I do to_f I get something like 16.0 (and as you can see Ruby is considering the , as a . for some reason)

Ruby is not treating the `,` as a `.` at all. If it would the resulting float would be `16.414` and not `16.0`. Ruby is just noticing an *extraneous* character and decides to ignore `,414`.

> How to accomplish that?

Well if you want `16,414` to be transformed to `16414` there's nothing as easy as just removing the character:

```
str = '16,414'
str.delete(',').to_i
# => 16414
```

In some cultures the `,` is considered a floating point. In that case, if you want to return `16.414` you can just transform the `,` into `.` and convert to `Float`:

```
str = '16,414'
str.gsub(/,/, '.').to_f
# => 16.414
```

Comment: what's new in this answer.. I am finding..But nothing get..help please. :)

Answer (score 1):

> as you can see Ruby is considering the , as a . for some reason

Yes, it's all quite confusing:

> class String
>
> to_i(base=10) → integer
>
> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an
>   integer base base (between 2 and 36). Extraneous characters past the
>   end of a valid number are ignored.
>
> to_f → float
>
> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as a
>   floating point number. Extraneous characters past the end of a valid
>   number are ignored.

The ruby docs are public.  They are not secret.  In fact, you probably have the docs on your computer.  Try this:

```
$ ri String#to_i
```